# MySQL: How think about Null insert to foreign key column

Tags: database-design, mysql-5.6

I'm designing table relationship. I have an one question.

Parent: A table

Child: B table

```
Table: A
PK: id

---

Table: B
PK: id
Column: A_id(NOT NULL), desk, chair...
Option: CONSTRAINT `fk_B_A_id` FOREIGN KEY (`A_id`) REFERENCES `A` (`id`) 
        ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

My case is, `B` table sometimes has `A_id`, sometimes doesn't have `A_id`.

So I'm trying to insert `0` for `A_id` when `B` table doesn't need the `A_id` value. But `A` table doesn't have id `0`. As a result error occurs.

I'm thinking two solutions:

1. `A_id` can have `null`.
2. Dummy data (A.id=0) insert to A table when A table create.

If you have other idea Please tell me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the relationship for child `B` against `A` isn't mandatory then just allow `NULL` on the foreign key column. It's very common to do this.

**Don't** use a *default* record (like `ID = 0`) to match against when there shouldn't really be one, it will bring you more trouble that solutions (what data will this record have? what happens with `NOT NULL` columns?)